# SQL JAVA I'm trying to get the minimum of something and ID it gives me the right minimum but wrong ID from another row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get the id of the student in orderhistory table of the minimum orders date the statement returns correct date but the ID doesn't match the same row of the minimum date.

THIS IS THE TABLE I should get ID 5 because the returning date is minimum but I'm getting 1 instead 
[image]

And here is what I'm getting
[image]

Comment: I'm using it in Java.......

Comment: Can you answer my question if you know instead of asking me questions that is not related please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the minimum of all rows and the StudentID of the first row.

Try this instead:

```
select OrderDate, StudentID
from orderhistory
where CatalogNum = 2
and OrderDate = (
  select min(OrderDate) from orderhistory where CatalogNum = 2
);
```